# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket error when using SSH tunel

Tags: r, dplyr, ssh-tunnel, rmysql

I am trying to use dplyr to connect to a remote database, that I usually query through a ssh tunnel.

I first set up a ssh tunnel like the following:

```
alias tunnel_ncg='ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 mysqluser@myhost mysql5 -h 127.0.0.1:3306 -P 3307 -u mysqluser -p mypassword'
```

At this point I can access the database by connecting to localhost:3307. For example:

```
mysql -h '127.0.0.1' -P 3307 -u mysqluser
```

If I try to access the same database through dplyr, I get an error complaining that it can't connect to the local MySQL socket:

```
> conDplyr = src_mysql(dbname = "mydb", user = "mysqluser", password = "mypassword", host = "localhost", port=3307)
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My understanding is that RMySQL/dplyr are trying to looking for a socket file in the local computer, however they should really be looking for it in the remote server. Is there a way to fix this, or a work-around?

UPDATE:

If I try to connect through dbConnect/RMySQL, the connection works fine:

```
> dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"), user="mysqluser", password="mypassword", dbname="mydb", host="127.0.0.1", port=3307)
<MySQLConnection:0,1>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As silly as it sounds replacing `localhost` with an IP address (`127.0.0.1`) solves the problem.

```
src_mysql(
    dbname = "mydb", user = "mysqluser", password = "mypassword",
    host = "127.0.0.1", port=3307)
```

For an explanation take a look at the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connecting.html):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs.
>
> For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. **This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number**.
>
> To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server.

Comment: For my case, mysql was bound to local IP at 10.x.x.x, so I have to replace 127.0.0.1 to that instead.  Therefore, check etc/my.cnf on Linux to ensure you are using the right IP.

Comment: This worked for me. Strangely, Django Python would connect just fine, but R's various packages all refused! How annoying. Version: R 3.4.1.